# Why state declared via useState hook does not change?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, setstate, use-state

The method switchSection should change the index of currently displayed section to display the next section, index is declared a the current state, whenever user clicks enter key switchSection method executes, if currently displayed section is the latest of the list, the setCurrent should be set to zero, otherwise incremented by one. everything seems to be fine, but setCurrent does not modifies the current state

```
  export default () =>{
  const refs = []
  //Here is the state declaration
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0)
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', switchSection)
    return _ => window.removeEventListener('keyup', switchSection)
  }, [])

  const switchSection = event => {
    if(event.keyCode === 13) {
      refs[current].current.classList.remove('activeTabLink')
      //the line below does not change the state, the current remains 0
      current < refs.length - 1 ? setCurrent(prevVal => prevVal + 1) :  setCurrent(0)
      refs[current].current.classList.add('activeTabLink')
    }
  } 

  const changeActiveElement = (event) => {
    let buttons = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('tabLinks'))
    buttons.forEach(button => button.classList.remove('activeTabLink'))
    event.target.classList.add('activeTabLink')
    setCurrent(parseInt(event.target.id))
  }

  return (
    <div style={SSS()}>
      <Chapter additionalStyle={{textAlign: 'left', marginLeft: '2%'}}>Chapter</Chapter>
      <div className="tab">
        {history.links.map((link, index) => {
          const newRef = useRef(null);
          refs.push(newRef);
          if (index === 0) return <button className="tabLinks activeTabLink" ref={newRef} id={index} onClick={changeActiveElement} key={index}>{link}</button>
          else return <button className="tabLinks" ref={newRef} id={index} onClick={changeActiveElement} key={index}>{link}</button>
        })}
      </div>
      <div className="aboutContent">
        
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

> Blockquote

Comment: your error is here. setCurrent(prevVal => prevVal + 1)  abstract that logic to a constant and pass it along again on your ternary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you've already checked that `current < refs.length` is actually evaluating to `true`? That would be the first place I look, but I don't have enough information to check that. A good way to check that is remove the ternary operator, use an if-else and throw in a console.log or run in a debugger and step through.

Next, keep in mind that in the line below:

```
current < refs.length - 1 ? setCurrent(prevVal => prevVal + 1) :  setCurrent(0)
```

the value of `current` and `prevVal` may be different if multiple set states are happening in one render. If you know this won't happen you could do this.

```
current < refs.length - 1 ? setCurrent(current + 1) : setCurrent(0)
```

That being said, I'd recommend just doing it this way so you don't close over the last render's value:

```
 setCurrent(prevVal => {
   return prevVal < refs.length - 1 ? prevVal + 1 : 0;
 });
```

But that probably isn't your error. I'm guessing your `setCurrent(prevVal => prevVal + 1)` is never getting called.

Comment: Yep, setCurrent(prevVal => { return prevVal < refs.length - 1 ? prevVal + 1 : 0; }); works, thank you :)